# problems with the plist output values

Tags: objective-c, ios4, plist

It is my first time using a plist as a way to store a little data for my application. My problem now is my application is giving a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. In my method to read the plist, it gave me `summary unavailable`. But the NSMutableDictionary gave me 2 key/paired, which my plist only had 2 values just to learn how to use plist (for now). I have a feeling, due to this Summary Unavailable`, I got the`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error?

```
-(void)readFile{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EventAddress.plist"]; //3

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; // 5

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    //load from savedStock both addr and event are NSString
    addr = [savedStock objectForKey:@"Address"];
    event = [savedStock objectForKey:@"Event"];

    [savedStock release];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

```
Where the error occurred was at the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    ...
    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS happened at this line
    [[cell textLabel] setText:addr];
}
```

But that was settled when @Jeff told me to retain the addr and event. Now my new `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is coming from the main.m file:
`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

What could have gone wrong now?

**UPDATE 2** 
This is the site I learnt how to use plist. 
[plist tutorial](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/)

Comment: Which line is getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: sorry, didnt write the question properly. addr and event are both suppose to display in a `UITableViewCell` `[[cell textLabel] setText:addr];` I will try @Jeff's reply and then update this question. thanks for your quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the values of `addr` and `event` after this? They aren’t being retained, so when `savedStock` is dellocated, they will be too. If those are instance variables, retain them when you pull them out of the dictionary.